# Meaning of 家族のありがたさ

Tags: grammar

I recently came across this: 家族のありがたさをつくづくと感じる

On first inspection I presumed it meant that he was feeling how grateful his family was **of him** however the text was translated as:

> 家族のありがたさをつくづくと感じる - I feel deeply grateful to my family

How can you tell whether it was the family's gratefulness or person/author?
Thanks

Comment: If you look 有難さ up in the jisho.org, it actually means "value, virtue, blessing", not "gratefulness" as one would expect. I'm not a native so I can't be 100% sure, but if this is correct then it changes the entire meaning of the sentence. The sentence would probably literally mean "I keenly feel the virtues/value of my family."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got a bit too curious for my own good and looked it up. I think the assumption in my comment was correct. 有難さ doesn't actually mean gratefulness according to [kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9C%89%E9%9B%A3%E3%81%95-2003994). It actually means "something to be grateful for" or "value". I found two examples where it actually expresses this. The first is an example I found on [tatoeba](https://tatoeba.org/jpn/sentences/show/143640).

> 水不足の時、水のありがたさを骨身にしみて感じた。
>
>  During the water shortage, the value of water really came home to me.

Another one I found was a sentence on a [hinative post](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/3961036) comparing 有難み and 有難さ. They essentially mean the  same thing.

> 大人になって、初めて親のありがたさがわかる。
>
>  Once I became an adult, I finally realized (how much my parents did for me / that I should be grateful for my parents).

If you think about it, this makes sense. 有難い doesn't actually describe a grateful person, it expresses that you are grateful for what it describes. For example, 有難いこと means "something that (we) should be grateful for. You wouldn't say 私は有難い.

So, I think the original translation of your sentence was correct. I hope this clears things up. Also, if I got something wrong, please correct me.

Edit:
Here's another example I found on Weblio

> あなたのそのお気持ちは大変有難い。
> I am grateful for your feelings.

Comment: I realized I didn't really address the order of の, but I think you already know that in AのB, A always describes/possesses B.